# Plotly - Invert Legend Click Selection?

Tags: plotly

In plotly, clicking an item in the legend will remove that item from the plot. Is it possible to invert this action? I.e., If I click on an item in the legend, it'll remove everything except that selection?

I often have 15-20 entities in a plot and want users to be able to remove noise quickly.

Comment: I don't think its possible to do it in current version of plotly

Answer (score 3):

### 1) This is standard

This is already a standard feature of plotly graphs. From my testing, the state management is like this.

**If showing:**

- 1 click = hide trace
- 2 clicks = hide every other trace

**If hidden:**

- 1 or 2 clicks = show trace

**If only shown trace:**

- 1 click = hide trace
- 2 clicks = show all traces (does not save previous state)

### 2) Visible Property

If you wish to control the visibility of a trace from code, set the `visible` property of the trace's `layout` to a valid value [`True`, `False`, `legendonly`]. See [plotly docs](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#scatter-visible).