# Control legend behavior using Plotly's highlight feature

Tags: python, plot, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

current code is when we select legend the data point vanishes. What I want is the opposite. I want is the opposite, Highlight, Mark the data point.

I checked
[Control legend behavior using Plotly's highlight feature with ggplotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59442233/control-legend-behavior-using-plotlys-highlight-feature-with-ggplotly)
and
[Plotly - Invert Legend Click Selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39258013/plotly-invert-legend-click-selection)

Tried to convert into python

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import dash
from dash import dcc, html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.express as px

# Load the iris dataset from plotly
iris = px.data.iris()

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

# Initial scatter plot
fig = go.Figure()

for s in iris['species'].unique():
    subset = iris[iris['species'] == s]
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=subset['petal_length'],
        y=subset['petal_width'],
        mode='markers',
        name=s
    ))

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(id='iris-plot', figure=fig),
])

@app.callback(
    Output('iris-plot', 'figure'),
    Input('iris-plot', 'clickData')
)
def toggle_opacity(clickData):
    # If a legend item is clicked
    if clickData and 'curveNumber' in clickData['points'][0]:
        curveNumber = clickData['points'][0]['curveNumber']
        current_opacity = fig.data[curveNumber].marker.opacity
        new_opacity = 0.3 if current_opacity == 1 else 1
        fig.data[curveNumber].marker.opacity = new_opacity
    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? This is using the algorithmic logic of the current code you have exactly, but simply swapping opacity for a different attribute of the plotly plot data.

```py
import dash
from dash import dcc, html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

iris = px.data.iris()

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

fig = go.Figure()

for s in iris["species"].unique():
    subset = iris[iris["species"] == s]
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x=subset["petal_length"],
            y=subset["petal_width"],
            mode="markers",
            name=s,
            marker=dict(size=6),
        )
    )

app.layout = html.Div([dcc.Graph(id="iris-plot", figure=fig)])


@app.callback(Output("iris-plot", "figure"), Input("iris-plot", "clickData"))
def toggle_marker_size(clickData):
    if clickData and "curveNumber" in clickData["points"][0]:
        curveNumber = clickData["points"][0]["curveNumber"]
        current_size = fig.data[curveNumber].marker.size
        new_size = 12 if current_size == 6 else 6
        fig.data[curveNumber].marker.size = new_size
    return fig


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

gives:

[image: Video screen recording showing example dash app where clicking data 'highlights' it by increasing marker size selectively]

---

#### Or, if what you want is changing "LegendClick" behavior

<sub>I'm not sure that can easily (if at all) be done using the built-in available Dash component properties of `dcc.Graph` (e.g., there is no `LegendClick`). But, an easy workaround would be to simply set the legend to be not shown (i.e., turn off the visibility of the legend explicitly), and in its place create your own legend out of a different kind of Dash object(s), say radio buttons for example, which could be pretty easily programmed with a callback where when toggled they "highlight" data.</sub>